# Different count of records when query executed from server

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, datareader

I have a query that is executed on SQL Server Database. I use a VPN to connect to the Database server. I am reading the results of query using ADO .NET DataReader. When I execute the code on my local machine I get all expected results, when my code runs in production in an Amazon server with VPN connected I get just a few results.

I am using .Net Core 2.2 and Sql Server Microsoft SQL Server 2017

```cs
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
{
     await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
     SqlCommand command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
     command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TestTable";             
     Int32 count = 0;
     var dr = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
     while (await dr.ReadAsync())
     {
          count++;
     }          

}
```

count should be TestTable's total number of rows (60k), but it's lower.

I also did the following test:

```cs
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
{
     await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
     SqlCommand commandCount = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
     commandCount.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TestTable";
     Int32 expectedCount = (Int32)commandCount.ExecuteScalar();

     SqlCommand command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
     command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TestTable";             
     Int32 count = 0;
     var dr = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
     while (await dr.ReadAsync())
     {
          count++;
     }          
     var areEqual = expectedCount == count;

}
```

Variable areEqual should be true, but it's false because count is always lower than expectedCount.
The expectedCount is like 60k and count is like 1k.
This problem only happens when the query is executed in production server.
I'm running the code in a console application.

I think there is a problem with the connection to the database, because if dispose the Datareader after reading all results I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Internal connection fatal error.
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryCloseInternal(Boolean closeReader)
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Close()
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
>     at System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.Dispose()

EDIT:
I tried removing the async methods but still got the same results:

```cs
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
{
     sqlConnection.Open();
     SqlCommand command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
     command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TestTable";             
     Int32 count = 0;
     var dr = command.ExecuteReader();
     while (dr.Read())
     {
          count++;
     }          

}
```

EDIT 1:
I tried the same code but using full .NET Framework 4.7.1 and got same wrong results

EDIT 2:
Installed SSMS in production server and when executing the query I get the following error:
An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Internal connection fatal error. Error state: 15, Token : 48

Comment: are you certain you're connecting to the same copy of the database in each case?

Comment: Also, counting is a very synchronous task.  Get rid of the async crap and see if you get the same results.

Comment: Make sure you have current backups,  verify your database integrity, and check the SQL Log for any corresponding error messages.  This could be a database corruption, or a bug.  You are on the unpatched RTM of SQL 2017.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4047329/sql-server-2017-build-versions

Comment: @ADyson yes i am using the same connection string in both cases. I created a sample console application just to test this cases with exact same connection string.

Comment: When you run the same query from SSMS, how many rows are you getting?

Comment: Just because you use the same connection string does not mean you are talking to the same server. Provide the connection string in your question

Comment: And that ip is a actual ip/dns name, not localhost or `(local)` or anything else weird?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I updated the question to show the error I'm getting using SSMS

Comment: `Error message is: Internal connection fatal error. Error state: 15, Token : 48`  The SQL Log may have more information, but looks like a possibly a bug, a database corruption.

Comment: Could be packet fragmentation playing ducks and drakes with your VPN connection. Make sure that the VPN's MTU (Maximum Transmission Unit) value is the same as or less than the MTU configured on your office router's internet connection. Preferably the same.